# Load a view controller created inside a storyboard as a subview (into a part of the screen) of another view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am currently developing as app for iPad. And I need to create a tabbar. The problem is that, for design purposes, I need the tabbar to be on the top half of the screen and not on the bottom as it is on the default tabbar controller.

Once the tabbar is on top I want that when a button is touched, the subview bellow the tab is changed. Furthermore, the subview that should be loaded was alson designed inside the storyboard. The following sketch shows what I want it to look like:

[image]

On my research I found a solution ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786648/on-top-tabbar-controller-or-segmented)) for putting the tabbar on top. Now my problem is on loading a subview bellow it.

I tried it with `[self.view addsubview:theNameOfTheViewCreatedINStoryboad.view]` but the application simply hangs when I press the button.

I think that is because I am not specifying anywhere what should be the dimension of the new view or where on the scree should it be placed. The reason for that is because I do not know where it should be done.

Can anyone give me some lights on this matter? Is the referred approach the best one for putting a tabbar on top? How can I solve the subview problem?

Comment: You say your app hangs, you mean it crashes?

Comment: No, it does not crashes just hangs. At least, for what I know, when it crashes a debug messages appears inside xcode right?

Comment: What do you mean it hangs then? it gets stuck? maybe you have a breakpoint? iOS apps don't hang unless you have an infinite loop somewhere. Try going to XCode when it hangs and hit the pause button, see what it's doing

Comment: Everytime I pause it this is where xcode indicates it is: http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/9597/capturevwo.png

Comment: The important is actually the stack trace on the left. Is it at one of your functions? what are the other threads doing?

Comment: I think it is not on any of my functions: http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/3999/capture2oq.png

(I'm a newbie using the debugger... )

Comment: Maybe it isn't stuck and there's some userInteractionEnabled issue? maybe you are adding a view somewhere that blocks your touches to your tab bar and so it looks like its hung?

Comment: Yes that is possible. Thus, my question on how to specify where the subview will be displayed... Do you understand what I mean? EDIT: I am assuming that it is possible to display the view somewhere outside the screen, because inside the screen the view isn't displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to see you are using a toolBar and not a tabBar. Even better would be to create a custom content view controller.

You should be looking into using containment:

[UIViewController containment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286554/uiviewcontroller-containment)
[How does View Controller Containment work in iOS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379759/how-does-view-controller-containment-work-in-ios-5)
[positioning UIViewController containment children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727123/positioning-uiviewcontroller-containment-children)

check out the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Due to deadline restrictions I have postponed this issue, but I will investigate this as soon as possible and will come back with feedback.